# Convert filename in NSString to UIImage for photo stored in asset library

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uiimage, alassetslibrary

I've managed to get the original filename of a photo stored in the asset-library using the following code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:project.photo];
        ALAssetsLibrary* library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [library assetForURL:url resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

            ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];

            _filename = [rep filename];
            NSLog(@"filename for image is: %@", _filename);

            if (_filename != nil)
            {

                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:_filename];
                NSLog(@"image is! %f", image.size.height);

                [image drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - image.size.width/2)/2, 350, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2)];

            }
```

The NSString variable _filepath is storing the original filepath of the image as:

```
IMG_0294.JPG
```

All I want to do is get this image from the photo gallery and draw it in a pdf document using the following code:

```
        [image drawInRect:CGRectMake( (pageSize.width - image.size.width/2)/2, 350, image.size.width/2, image.size.height/2)];
```

This draw code is definitely working, as I've tried it with an image stored in the application directory. I just need to find a way of using the filepath to either create a UIImage, or point it to the complete directory of that photo.

The image variable is returning as null when outputted to the console.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you grab the `url` of the photo rather than just the `filename`:

```
imageURL = [rep url];
```

You can the use this `imageURL` with the `ALAssetsLibrary` method  `assetForURL:resultBlock:failureBlock:` to create a UIImage.

There is lots of sample code out there showing how to use the `assetForURL` method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the image from the assets lib by going after it via a path or url.  You need to use, in your case, UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:rep.fullResolutionImage];

or fullScreenImage or whatever...